# What's the (Azure) role needed to reset the Linux VM password

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-rbac

I am trying to enhance my custom RBAC role by allowing users to reset their Linux VM

I couldn't able to find any exact role associated with the option for resetting the password for my Linux VM (see screenshot below)

[image]

Doing my own testing I found resetting password from Azure portal triggers the below API:

`/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/VMAccessLinuxPasswordReset-20220824203332?api-version=2020-06-01`

That means I have to provide `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` role to reset the password ? I was hesitant to give this access which can indirectly gives access to deploy any resources on RG level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no such role exiting to achieve my desired results. As i mentioned earlier the current design (role) needs `"Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*"` to allow the VM Password Reset.

I submitted a feedback for this to azure https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/75d7f38c-d934-ed11-a81b-000d3a04ded5 If you feel this could be something benefit for you, feel free to Upvote